# "Compile error: Variable not defined" for variable declared outside of a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I've just started studying **Excel VBA on Mac (Office 2016 for Mac)**. I coded as the textbook says, but it didn't work. The error message says `Compile error: Variable not defined`.

I added `Option Explicit` on the first line, declared a variable outside of a macro, and then wrote a macro with the variable. Is this a bug?

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim foo As Long

Sub Macro1()
    foo = 10
    Debug.Print "1: ", foo
End Sub
```

Comment: Sure that this is the complete code and that the error is related to your variable `foo`?

Comment: @ urdearboy: the comma is okay, it's not a syntax problem

Comment: @FunThomas SOLVED! The error has gone by commenting out other macros. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by other code. It seems that global variables must be declared before all macros.

```
Option Explicit

''''The error was caused by this macro''''
'Sub Macro0()
'    Dim foo As Long
'    foo = 10
'    foo = foo * 5
'    Debug.Print "foo's value: ", foo
'End Sub

Dim foo As Long

Sub Macro1()
    foo = 10
    Debug.Print "1: ", foo
End Sub
```